# 0x api - swapping ERC20 with ETH/WETH fails on Ropsten

Tags: web3js, 0x, solidity-0.8.x

Currently using IDENTICAL example from [0x starter guide](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api-starter-guide-code/blob/master/src/swap-contract.js).

Steps taken

1. deployed [contract](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api-starter-guide-code/blob/master/contracts/SimpleTokenSwap.sol) onto [ropsten network](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x3c9941a5271e4c58ea51c35452d5d663a95b587f)
2. Deposited test eth to the smart contract. Then tried swapping to some ERC20's successfully:

> { ETH: '100000000000000000',   WETH: '736120421643002',   DAI:
> '296138213008071359',   USDC: '6238118' }

3. Made sure allowance (owner = smart contract, spender = 0x allowanceTarget) for ERC20s were set to some high number

> { ETH: '0',   WETH:
> '115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935',
> DAI:
> '115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039454010447295162926691',
> USDC:
> '115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913115620207'
> }

4. tried swapping DAI for ETH via contract using swap-contract.js example from 0x.

```
const swap = {
    "sellTokenAddress" : "0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d", 
    "buyTokenAddress"   :"0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE",
    "sellAmount": 10000000000000000
};


const API_QUOTE_URL=`https://ropsten.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote`;

const qs = createQueryString({
    "sellToken" : swap['sellTokenAddress'].toLowerCase(),
    "buyToken"  : swap['buyTokenAddress'].toLowerCase(),
    "sellAmount": swap['sellAmount'],
    "slippagePercentage" : 0.01
});

const response = await fetch(`${API_QUOTE_URL}?${qs}`);
const q1= {"json" : await response.json()};

const receipt = await contract.methods.fillQuote(
    q1.json.sellTokenAddress,
    q1.json.buyTokenAddress,
    q1.json.allowanceTarget,
    q1.json.to,
    q1.json.data
).send({
    from: account.address,
    value: q1.json.value,
    gasPrice: q1.json.gasPrice,
    gas: 500000
});
```

I tried few times but Im getting transaction revert w/o any clear message: [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io//tx/0xc719dae96440a0a817e8a3dbbc0c12189b352704e967bac2cc0274f8977bfb3c) and [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io//tx/0x68b34e2676d1a31dc07b13d20ade51c678142c73dfdcf89c867e6e03bc7669a1)

Where am I going wrong? (there's enough DAI in the smart contract, and with DAI allowance for 0x allowanceTarget set to max - 0xfff...ff)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the SimpleTokenSwap.fillQuote function only supports trading ERC20 tokens, try using WETH as the `buyToken` instead of ETH.

For reference, ETH does not have a `balanceOf` function which the fillQuote tries to call [here](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api-starter-guide-code/blob/master/contracts/SimpleTokenSwap.sol#L82), this is probably causing it to fail

Comment: Thanks! Ah, yes.. didn't realize eth and erc20 had different ways of checking balance.

But for some reason, DAI is giving a bit of headache: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123180/0x-api-fillquote-works-on-usdc-dai-but-not-dai-usdc

Comment: Any idea what this error is? I'm using the same code, except I'm submitting the tx by multiplying quoted gas by 3 using quote where I don't specify takerAddress.  
```
Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="toNumber", value="285837258167192856142155196896925256079494159121", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)
```

This happens randomly.